# Clip linesegment at a polygon boundary using turfjs

Tags: javascript, clip, splitting, turf

Having a linestring and a polygon, Is there a way to clip the linesegment at the boundary of the polygon and retain the shape of the linestring which runs inside the polygon?

Example Linestring

> {
>     "type": "FeatureCollection",
>     "features": [
>       {
>         "type": "Feature",
>         "properties": {},
>         "geometry": {
>           "type": "LineString",
>           "coordinates": [
>             [
>               -43.154296875,
>               38.34165619279595
>             ],
>             [
>               -11.42578125,
>               46.13417004624326
>             ]
>           ]
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   }

Example Polygon

> {
>     "type": "FeatureCollection",
>     "features": [
>       {
>         "type": "Feature",
>         "properties": {},
>         "geometry": {
>           "type": "Polygon",
>           "coordinates": [
>             [
>               [
>                 -35.947265625,
>                 28.998531814051795
>               ],
>               [
>                 -21.62109375,
>                 28.998531814051795
>               ],
>               [
>                 -21.62109375,
>                 48.3416461723746
>               ],
>               [
>                 -35.947265625,
>                 48.3416461723746
>               ],
>               [
>                 -35.947265625,
>                 28.998531814051795
>               ]
>             ]
>           ]
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   }

I want to know how I can clip the linesegment which crosses the polygon as a separate feature? I tried turf's `lineSplit` and `lineIntersect`. But was not able to combine multiple functions to get the required output. 
Trying to understand turfs functions. Any help will be very helpful.

Thnak you.

Answer (score 1):

Combine multiple functions?  I'm surprised that [lineSplit()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineSplit) didn't work for you, since that's the answer to "how do you clip a line with Turf.js?"  Were you receiving an error, and could you share your code here?

If the polygon is giving you trouble, you could convert it to a line first with [polygonToLine()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#polygonToLine).

[lineIntersect()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineIntersect) returns the points of intersection between input features, so I don't think that you'll need it to accomplish this task.